# Regexp match until

Tags: regex, json

I have the following string:

```
{"name":"db-mysql","authenticate":false,"remove":false,"skip":false,"options":{"create":{"Image":"mysql:5.6/image-name:0.3.44","Env":{"MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD":"dummy_pass","MYSQL_DATABASE":"dev_db"}}}}
```

I need to get the version: 0.3.44

The pattern will always be "Image":"XXX:YYY/ZZZ:VVV"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/10RECcV1Ij)

Comment: Any reason of not using a JSON API?

Comment: If you insist on using regex, then the following works: `"Image":"(.*?):(.*?)\/(.*?):(.*?)"`. [Rubular Link](http://www.rubular.com/r/3OMTYfAnT4).

Comment: It *sometimes* works.

Comment: And it does not only match the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will reliably match the given "pattern" in any string and capture the group designated `VVV`:

```
/"Image":"[^:"]+:[^"\/]+\/[^":]+:([^"]+)"/
```

where the pattern is understood to express the following characteristics of the input to be matched:

- there is no whitespace around the colon between `"Image"` and the following `"` (though that could be matched with a small tweak);
- the `XXX` and `ZZZ` substrings do contain any colons;
- the `YYY` substring does not contain a forward slash (`/`); and
- none of the substrings `XXX`, `YYY`, `ZZZ`, or `VVV` contains a literal double-quote (`"`), whether or not escaped.

Inasmuch as those constraints are stronger than JSON or YAML requires to express the given data, you'd probably be better off using using a bona fide JSON / YAML parser.  A real parser will cope with semantically equivalent inputs that do not satisfy the constraints, and it will recognize invalid (in the JSON or YAML sense) inputs that contain the pattern.  If none of that is a concern to you, however, then the regex will do the job.

Comment: It looks good to me, I was about to post `"Image":"[^:]*:[^\/]*\/[^:]*:[^"]*"` which is a bit less strict. Depends on what the OP really wants. Using regex in this case is not pretty anyways.. [rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/uQVKXmdcOd)

Comment: Not so fast, @ikegami.  I listed the specific criteria that qualify my claim that the regex is reliable.  Recognizing broken JSON is not a given requirement.  Supporting string delimiters other than `"` is not a requirement.  Please support your claim with an example of an input that satisfies those constraints and which the regex either falsely matches or incorrectly fails to match.

Comment: @ikegami, Extra whitespace (between "Image": and the value, I assume you mean) does not fit the pattern to be matched, therefore is irrelevant.  The regex could nevertheless match it with a minor tweak.  `\` escapes are not an issue, except for escaped `"` which violate the constraints given.  Multiple "Image" elements are not a problem for the pattern -- it will match one at a time, if indeed more than one matches, without false positives.

Comment: @ikegami, And I'm asking for examples because you have falsely contradicted my answer.  Moreover, although I agree that a real parser would be better, the question title asks for regex.

Comment: @ikegami, the examples you parametrically *described* do not contradict my answer.  But whatever.

Comment: @ikegami, I claim that the regex will do what I say it will do under the circumstances I claim it will do so.  Every time.  That's what reliability means.

Comment: @ikegami, your simpler regex matches this input that does not conform to the pattern: "Image":"foo:bar:baz/twiddle/twaddle:123".  Mine does not.

Comment: Why do you keep breaking your answer? I fixed it so your first statement is true, but you keep making it false. **Your regex pattern is not even close to being reliable**. You make far more assumptions that you claim. It's one thing to make a mistake, but your intentional lies are disappointing.

Comment: Re " Mine does not.", I know; you don't need to convince me your solution is unreliable; I've been saying it all along.

Comment: The example input I gave does not fit the pattern given to be matched, yet your regex matches it.  That's a false positive.

Comment: You cannot redefine the question to suit you.  I answered the question that was posed.

Comment: Apparently, you don't know the meaning of reliable. **Reliability is how well something handles change, and yours handles variations *extremely* poorly.** @Zaibes, I'd strongly recommend that you stay as far from it as possible.

Comment: "Reliability" is whether something can be relied upon to behave as promised.  My regex will behave exactly as promised, for *all* inputs to which that promise applies, which inputs are completely described in the answer.  It is possible that the OP's real requirements are different than those expressed in his question, but only he can judge that.

Comment: Thanks John and sorry ikegami. There won't be any variation. I need to get this version from a json. The fact that the version number is not in a json property itself prevent me to do some nice manipulation. I could get 'Image' property and retrieve the value '"Image":"mysql:5.6/huhu:0.3.44' but would still need to do some nasty parsing to get 0.3.44. I guess a regex suits my need

Comment: Re "but would still need to do some nasty parsing", Not at all; you could do some nice proper parsing as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely hard to do correctly using just a regular expression, and it would require an regex engine capable of recursion. Rather than writing a 50 line regexp, I'd simply use an existing JSON parser.

```
$ perl -MJSON::PP -E'
   use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
   my $json = <>;
   my $data = JSON::PP->new->decode($json);
   my $image = $data->{options}{create}{Image};
   my %versions = map { split(/:/, $_, 2) } split(/\//, $image);
   say $versions{"image-name"};
' my.json
0.3.44
```